# Several python modules like RPIO and queue seem to have trouble installing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I tried running `pip install RPIO` and found that in the process of installation, the following error occurs.

```
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\xxxxxx\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build- 
ef4z2k\\RPIO\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\temp\pip-3_ddbu-record\install-record.txt --
single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in 
c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ef4z2k\RPIO\
```

Most modules get installed without any such issue. I installed plotly and scipy modules right before these, and no issues were faced there. Any idea where I might be going wrong?